# What is the purpose of doOnNext(...) in RxJava

Tags: java, rx-java

When should we use [doOnNext()](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#doOnNext-rx.functions.Action1-) from Observable instead of just onNext()?

Comment: I notice you are using [system.reactive] for non Rx.NET questions... bear in mind this is for .NET Rx questions. Questions specifically targeting RxJava should not use it.

Comment: I noticed that `rx` is a synonym for `system.reactive` - trying to get this addressed on meta, so that it's a separate more general tag.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

`doOnNext` is for side-effects: you want to react (eg. log) to item emissions in an intermediate step of your stream, for example before the stream is filtered, for transverse behavior like logging, but you still want the value to propagate down the stream.

`onNext` is more final, it consumes the value.

Comment: I am wondering why I can't put the "log" statements directly in Observable...i.e. the class that calls onNext(...) on the subscribers/observers

Comment: You definitely can. It's just that this value could have been lost by subsequent transformations (eg logging all values in a doOnNext then filtering some and applying onNext on the filtered ones only)

Comment: What do you call `onNext` on?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky `onNext` is part of the `Observer` (or `Subscriber`) interface, the one you plug in at the end of your stream via `subscribe(...)` methods to consume the final values in the stream

Comment: @SimonBaslé which scheduler does it run on?

Comment: @sebastian the same as onNext, so if you use eg `observeOn(x)` it would be that one

Answer (score 27):

*IMPORTANT EDIT*: -in bold characters immediately below-

*** Once one grasps the concept,
I warmly suggest you to have a look at this [link](https://proandroiddev.com/briefly-about-rxjava-logging-20308b013e6d), is a lifechanger, not  only because we use different observable as  `Observable`, `Single`, `Maybe` that could be need a different tool as `doOnEvent()` for `Single` and `doOnEach()` for `Observable` but because if you want to debug, there are some reasons why doOnNext() could often even not be the ideal choice, because we could ignore other events that are relevant to resolve the problem***

ORIGINAL REPLY: -partially modified-

First of all `doOnNext()` can be called **even more times** in the chain of operators between Observable and Subscribe, this gives to you greater possibilities to debug your code. Because of its "stream" nature, is not easy to do debugging in RXJava, `doOnNext()` instead makes debugging easier. At this purpose you may consider also to combine it with the`doOnError()` operator. Why not using a simple `onNext()`? Because debugging is not strictly related to the logic of the code, in theory you could also eliminate the `doOnNext()` before to go in production.

A really essential thing to understand is that given an Observable to subscribe long chain, you can use the doOnNext in a particular point, to see what an operator is giving back to another one:

For instance :

```
Observable.just("Donald", "Duck", "Mickey", "Goofy",
                "Uncle")
                .doOnNext{System.out.println("Here ou will get the strings above:$it ")}
                 .map{it.length}
                 .subscribe { println("Here you will get the numbers of how every string is long: $it") }}
```

A typical use case to employ `doOnNext()` could for example occur when you want to cache a response from a server, so for instance you could use `map()` but [also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30149692/rxjava-alternative-for-map-operator-to-save-emitted-items?noredirect=1&lq=1) `doOnNext()`, because it allows you to make your code more readable as instead you would put a simple `onNext()` that ideally could have been structured to follow other instructions. (This is arguable, as all the architectural thoughts)

Equally to `doOnNext()` and for the same debugging purposes
you could use others self-explanatory operators:

> doOnSubscribe(), doOnUnsubscribe(), doOnCompleted(), doOnError(),
>   doOnTerminate(),finallyDo(), doOnEach(), doOnRequest()

`doOnNext()` allow you to see what is going on into the Observable (often really long) chains, what is really important is that **you can kinda spying what is going on trough the chain, without affecting any operation, without making any transformation( let's say not properly a kind of `Log.d` we use in imperative, not reactive code).** This is is the reason why is called a ***side*** effect.

EDIT(because of the question in the comments):

`doOnNext()` and the method above are just callbacks, please refer to [that](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/do.html), `doOnNext()` as the official documentation says

> just modifies an Observable so that it invokes an action when it calls
>   onNext.

Really simple, this is why is called sometimes to upload the progress bar, but also is really used in the repository pattern, for instance if you want to store data to the db/or caching after a call to retrofit for instance.

If you are really curious under the hood the doSomethingReactive methods just call the method `call()` ( a callback from the Interface Action) inside the "real" method SomethingReactive

Comment: Is it right: onNext executes only after all doOnNext's finish their tasks? Like if I modify value in doOnNext, onNext will receive this modified value?

Comment: No I do not think is right. I added an editcomment to make you more understandable the doOnWhatever reactive, please refer to that above. doOnNext get executed just BEFORE EVERY onNext is called! As you can easily see from an example with Log you can make yourself

Comment: Now that's one heck of an answer. Great job

Comment: can I call doOnNext(consumer) multiple times before subscribing and it will execute accept() on all of the consumers?

Comment: @OfefRegev,  I tried to call `doOnNext` more times before subscribing, consecutively and it works. Anyway is out from the scope of the question, that is when to use `doOnNext` and not how to use it. In general if you play a bit, is a great way to learn, start from a simple example in the web and then add multiple `doOnNext`. If you get stuck write a new post, if you like you can send me a message you have some issue and I will try to help you.

Comment: I'd like to caution anyone reading this answer from interacting with the UI (showing a progress bar) in `doOnNext`. As the accepted answer mentions, `doOnNext` should be used for side effects. The UI is not a side effect. While you may not run into trouble with a trivial example, treating the UI as a side effect can create some pretty nasty state management issues in a more complex situation. See [Managing State with RxJava by Jake Wharton](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0IKHxjkgop4) for more information. Jump to 16:30 for the TL;DR.

Comment: @luis_cortes thank you very much for your intervention, I did this post when I was kind of junior, now I erased the progress bar content, and added some new imo important content regarding the limits of doOnNext to debug( hoping to not go out of  OP question scope), once a coder is starting to write more complex chains, please double check if you like

Comment: When/why would one use `subscribe` over `doOnNext`?

Comment: subscribe is the default behaviour @Tobiq without subscribe you do not get working nothing, the Observable is not pushed, is "dead" so you need always to use `subscribe`. Whereas the usage of the `do` is to use some side effects, that is something that in theory should not happen in a functional pure program, but this is an advanced topic you can find on the internet looking for functional side effects, some example are in mine reply, so instead to go linear from A to B you do `A->X ->B`

Answer (score 2):

`doOnNext()` allows us to add some extra action that happens every time we get a new data item.

doOnError does not handle the error, in the sense that it does not consume one. He just does something with it, like records it. (The same is true for doOnNext - it doesn't consume the element either, and the element still ends up in the onNext Subscriber).

```
Observable.just("Some data...")
                .doOnNext(System.out::println)
                .doOnNext(value -> System.out.println("before transform: " + value+" You can add something here but it dont affect in data"))
                .map(value -> value + "| adding some new data")
                .doOnNext(value -> System.out.println("after transform: " + value))
                .subscribe(onNext -> {
            System.out.println("onNext: "+onNext); // print out the remaining numbers
        });
```

Result:

> Some data...
>
> before transform: Some data...You can add something here but it dont
> affect in data
>
> after transform: Some data...| adding some new data
>
> onNext: Some data...| adding some new data