# RxJava, How to update views at different states of Observables call chain?

Tags: rx-java, rx-android

I need to perform one task using one Observable, obtaining the emitted data, then using another Observable to do another query. 
Normally I would use a `flatmap` to chain the two Observables and just caring about the final piece of data emitted.
Now there's a need to update the view during the process. Say when the first Observable emit data, I should show a text line on the UI.

I know I can break it down to two call times, calling the 2nd Observable inside `onNext()` of the first one, but that's cumbersome.

How can I achieve what I described above without going down that path?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example from ny old project with [doOnNext()](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#doOnNext(rx.functions.Action1)):

```
API.getVideoListObservable()
                .doOnError(t -> t.printStackTrace())
                .map(r -> r.getObjects())
                .doOnNext(l -> VideoActivity.this.runOnUiThread(() -> fragment.updateVideoList(l)))
                .doOnNext(l -> kalturaVideoList.addAll(l))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe();
```

**Pay attention** to the `.doOnNext(l -> VideoActivity.this.runOnUiThread(() -> fragment.updateVideoList(l)))` - after it you can use `flatmap()` any times, and `doOnNext()` will be executed before `flatmap()`

Good explanation of `doOnNext()` by Simon Baslé [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28405340/1796309):

> `doOnNext` is for side-effects: you want to react (eg. log) to item
>   emissions in an intermediate step of your stream, for example before
>   the stream is filtered, for transverse behavior like logging, but you
>   still want the value to propagate down the stream.
>
> `onNext` is more final, it consumes the value.