# Using RxJava to join local data with remote ( or cached ) data

Tags: android, rx-java, kotlin, rx-kotlin

This is working code but I have a few questions as well as a request for advice on improving it. I am new to RxJava and I have not fully wrapped my head around how to chain these type of observables together.

I have two model objects, `ListItem` and `UserInfo`. `ListItem`s exists in a local database and the `UserInfo` is fetched from the server by using an ID provided from the `ListItem`.

The `UserInfo` web service accepts an array of IDs for which it will return a list of `UserInfo` objects.

The flow of this code is as follows:

1. Load `ListItem`s from database
2. Using the `ListItem`s fetched from the database, check an in memory cache to see if I've already fetched the `UserInfo` for a particular `ListItem`
3. For any items whose `UserInfo` is not cached, fetch them from the network
4. Place the fetched `UserInfo` objects into the cache
5. Re-run step 2 ( the method is `loadCachedUserInfo`)
6. Return results to subscriber

NOTE: The `UserInfo` objects should only be fetched for a `ListItem` if the list has been deemed a `isUserList`.

Here is the code:

```
fun itemsInList(list : ATList, parentValue : String? = null, searchString : String? = null, limit : Int = defaultFetchLimit, sortOrder: SortDescriptor? = null) : Observable<List<ATListItem>> {
    return Observable.create<List<ATListItem>> { subscriber ->
        val listItems = listItemsInList(list, parentValue = parentValue, searchString = searchString, limit = limit, sortOrder = sortOrder)
        subscriber.onNext(listItems)
        subscriber.onCompleted()
    }.flatMap { listItems ->
        if ( list.isUserList ) {
            return@flatMap loadCachedUserInfo(listItems, userIDIndex = list.userIDIndex!!)
        }
        return@flatMap Observable.just(listItems)
    }.flatMap { listItems ->
        if ( list.isUserList ) {
            return@flatMap fetchUserInfoForListItems(listItems, list.userIDIndex!!, force = false)
        }
        return@flatMap Observable.just(listItems)
    }
}

fun loadCachedUserInfo(listItems : List<ATListItem>, userIDIndex : Int) : Observable<List<ATListItem>> {
    return Observable.create<List<ATListItem>> { subscriber ->
        for ( listItem in listItems ) {
            listItem.coreUserInfo = coreUserMap[listItem.valueForAttributeIndex(userIDIndex)?.toLowerCase()]
        }
        subscriber.onNext(listItems)
        subscriber.onCompleted()
    }
}

fun fetchUserInfoForListItems(listItems : List<ATListItem>, userIDIndex: Int, force: Boolean) : Observable<List<ATListItem>> {
    val itemsToFetch = if ( force ) listItems else listItems.filter { it.coreUserInfo == null }
    val ids = itemsToFetch.map { it.valueForAttributeIndex(userIDIndex) ?: "" }.filter { !it.isEmpty() }
    val records = hashMapOf("records" to ids)
    if ( itemsToFetch.count() == 0 ) {
        return Observable.just(listItems)
    }
    return RuntimeDataController.dataService.fetchCoreUserInfo(recordsMap = records)
            .map { json ->
                val recordsArray = json.arrayValue("records")
                for ( i in 0..recordsArray.length() - 1) {
                    val coreUserInfo = CoreUserInfo(recordsArray.getJSONObject(i))
                    coreUserMap[coreUserInfo.username.toLowerCase()] = coreUserInfo
                    coreUserMap[coreUserInfo.userID] = coreUserInfo
                    coreUserInfo.externalUserID?.let { coreUserMap[it] = coreUserInfo }
                }
                return@map listItems
            }.flatMap { loadCachedUserInfo(listItems, userIDIndex = userIDIndex) }
}
```

The user would initiate the sequence of events by calling:

`ListController.itemsInList(list)`

My questions about this code are:

1. Currently `loadCachedUserInfo` takes in an array of `ListItem` and returns that same array as an observable after the cached items have been associated with it. This feels wrong to me. I think instead this call should only return the items that have a cached `UserInfo` associated with it. However, I need to continue passing the full array of `ListItem` to the next method

2.) Do I need to do additional work to support unsubscribing?

3.) This is similar question 1. My `fetchUserInfoForListItems` takes an array of list items and returns an observable with that same array of list items after they have been fetched and re-run through the cache method. This also feels incorrect to me. I would rather this method return an `Observable<List<UserInfo>>` for the objects that were fetched. I am not understanding how in `itemsInList` to then associate the `ListItem`s with the newly fetched `UserInfo` and return an Observable of those `ListItem`s.

**Edit**: After writing this post it gave helped me realize a few things. I can flatMap wrap my calls in an Observable.create that can contain the smarts I wanted to take out of my `fetchUserInfoForListItems`, letting me address question #3. Here is the updated code:

```
 fun itemsInList(list : ATList, parentValue : String? = null, searchString : String? = null, limit : Int = defaultFetchLimit, sortOrder: SortDescriptor? = null) : Observable<List<ATListItem>> {
    return Observable.create<List<ATListItem>> { subscriber ->
        val listItems = listItemsInList(list, parentValue = parentValue, searchString = searchString, limit = limit, sortOrder = sortOrder)
        subscriber.onNext(listItems)
        subscriber.onCompleted()
    }.flatMap { listItems ->
        if ( list.isUserList ) {
            return@flatMap loadCachedUserInfo(listItems, userIDIndex = list.userIDIndex!!)
        }
        return@flatMap Observable.just(listItems)
    }.flatMap { listItems ->
        if ( list.isUserList ) {
            return@flatMap Observable.create<List<ATListItem>> { subscriber ->
                fetchUserInfoForListItems(listItems, list.userIDIndex!!, force = false).map { userInfoList ->
                    for (coreUserInfo in userInfoList) {
                        coreUserMap[coreUserInfo.username.toLowerCase()] = coreUserInfo
                        coreUserMap[coreUserInfo.userID] = coreUserInfo
                        coreUserInfo.externalUserID?.let { coreUserMap[it] = coreUserInfo }
                    }
                }.flatMap {
                    loadCachedUserInfo(listItems, userIDIndex = list.userIDIndex!!)
                }.subscribe {
                    subscriber.onNext(listItems)
                    subscriber.onCompleted()
                }
            }
        }
        return@flatMap Observable.just(listItems)
    }
}

fun loadCachedUserInfo(listItems : List<ATListItem>, userIDIndex : Int) : Observable<List<ATListItem>> {
    return Observable.create<List<ATListItem>> { subscriber ->
        listItems.forEach { listItem -> listItem.coreUserInfo = coreUserMap[listItem.valueForAttributeIndex(userIDIndex)?.toLowerCase()] }
        subscriber.onNext(listItems)
        subscriber.onCompleted()
    }
}

fun fetchUserInfoForListItems(listItems : List<ATListItem>, userIDIndex: Int, force: Boolean) : Observable<List<CoreUserInfo>> {
    val itemsToFetch = if ( force ) listItems else listItems.filter { it.coreUserInfo == null }
    val ids = itemsToFetch.map { it.valueForAttributeIndex(userIDIndex) ?: "" }.filter { !it.isEmpty() }
    val records = hashMapOf("records" to ids)
    if ( itemsToFetch.count() == 0 ) { return Observable.just(ArrayList<CoreUserInfo>()) }
    return RuntimeDataController.dataService.fetchCoreUserInfo(recordsMap = records)
            .map { json ->
                val userInfo = ArrayList<CoreUserInfo>()
                json.arrayValue("records").eachObject { userInfo.add(CoreUserInfo(it)) }
                return@map userInfo
            }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Currently loadCachedUserInfo takes in an array of ListItem and returns that same array as an observable after the cached items have been associated with it. This feels wrong to me. I think instead this call should only return the items that have a cached UserInfo associated with it. However, I need to continue passing the full array of ListItem to the next method

I am not sure I understand you correctly but if you only need side-effect (caching), you can just use `doOnNext`. For example,

```
.doOnNext { listItems ->
    if ( list.isUserList ) {
        cache(listItems, userIDIndex = list.userIDIndex!!)
    }
}

fun cache(listItems : List<ATListItem>, userIDIndex : Int) {
    // caching
}
```

> 2. Do I need to do additional work to support unsubscribing?

No, AFAIK.

**Note:**

**More info about `doOnNext` can be found at [What is the purpose of doOnNext(...) in RxJava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28402689/what-is-the-purpose-of-doonnext-in-rxjava) and [here](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/rxjavas-side-effect-methods/)**

Normally you don't need `return@...` if the last statement in lambda is an expression. 
e.g.:

```
.flatMap { listItems ->
    if ( list.isUserList ) {
        return@flatMap loadCachedUserInfo(listItems, userIDIndex = list.userIDIndex!!)
    }
    return@flatMap Observable.just(listItems)
}
```

can be written like:

```
.flatMap { listItems ->
    if ( list.isUserList )
        loadCachedUserInfo(listItems, userIDIndex = list.userIDIndex!!)
    else
        Observable.just(listItems)
}
```

**I didn't test the code.**

Comment: Thanks, doOnNext was definitely the missing piece. I no longer need to make my cache store and lookup an observable method because I can do them in doOnNext which simplified everything.