# RxJava Observable doOnNext vs subscribe()

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm not quite understanding the difference between using an observable's doOnNext/doOnSubscribe/doOnComplete versus passing in an observer through the observable's subscribe function. These two seem to do the same thing to me. Can someone give me a use case where I would use one over the other?

```
                                Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                    .take(30)
                                    .map(v -> v + 1) 
                                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                    .doOnNext(new Consumer<Long>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void accept(Long aLong) throws Throwable {
                                            // update UI 
                                        }
                                    })

                            Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                    .take(30)
                                    .map(v -> v + 1)
                                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                    .subscribe(new Observer<Long>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {
                                            
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onNext(@NonNull Long aLong) {
                                              // update ui
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {

                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete() {

                                        }
                                    })
```

Comment: This helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/28405340/2649154.

Answer (score 0):

The `doOnNext` operator allows you to perform a side effect action, such as logging or additional processing, for each emitted item without modifying or consuming the item itself.

The `subscribe` method is used to consume the items and define the behavior of the Observer. This is typically the final step in the observable chain.

```
Observable.range(1, 5)
    .doOnNext(number -> System.out.println("Current number: " + number))//logging
    .map{number -> number*2}
    .subscribe(System.out::println); //will print [2,4,6,8,10]
```